# Golang http request POST works once

Tags: json, http, go

I have a master and slave. Master have api call result, which takes JSON. And i have proplem with slave, which send this result on master, the first time my code sends json well, but second time, code stop(program wait.....) on `resp, err := client.Do(req)`, when create query on master.
salve code:

```
func main (){
    for {
        // some code, very long code
        sendResult(resFiles)
    }
}

func sendResult(rf common.ResultFiles) {
    jsonValue, err := json.Marshal(rf)
    req, err := http.NewRequest(methodPost, ResultAdress, 
                                bytes.NewBuffer(jsonValue))
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", ContentType)
    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    fmt.Println("response Status:", resp.Status)
}
```

master api call:

```
func result(c echo.Context) error {
    rf := &ResultFiles{}
    err := c.Bind(rf)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    rfChannel <- *rf
    return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, nil)
}
```

My question: Why? May be problem in the standard client golang (http.Client) or timeout? If i set timout - my code crashed by timeout)))anticipated....
Thank you!

Comment: First verify where the issue is, client or server.  Does the server work if you perform the http post twice from some other tools, e.g. by using `curl` ? In which case it's your client that's the problem, or if you get the same issue by using existing tools to post to the server, it's your server that is the issue.

Comment: I check - problem with my master - with channel.

Comment: Ok, then you don't need to post the client code, but your server code. (we can't debug your server code based on just the small piece of code you have posted here though)

Comment: I understand, but first time i think problem in slave, now i solve problem and post result)))Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a timeout to your http.Client. By default http.Client has timeout specified as 0 which means no timeout at all. So if server is not responding than your application will just hang waiting for a response. This problem is fully described in this article [Don’t use Go’s default HTTP client (in production)](https://medium.com/@nate510/don-t-use-go-s-default-http-client-4804cb19f779). Though you create custom client you still need to specify timeout.

Comment: i read this article and set timout, but i get timeout error. I think may be problem on master, but when my slave wait answer, i call my master and I jerk api call my master and he returns me a answer. How?

Comment: It's hard to tell without looking at master's code for this endpoint. If I had to guess - check the code for infinite loops, sleeps, and blocking operations (like adding message to a buffered channel for example).

Comment: i add master  code, yes i have channel in my master.

Comment: i comment code which send result ot channel on master and master work good, See problem link with channel.

Answer (score 0):

Problem link with channel, i send result work slave on master to channel, but channel work without loop, i add loop for read data from channel and all work.